# Using sumif to calculate sum of orders between 2 calculated dates

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum

I have created a spreadsheet which contains all of my sales/expenses.  On the overview sheet, I wish to be able to view current income for the day, week, month, quarter and year.  I have calculated the start and end dates for each of these using a calculation based on (Today) so they auto populate.

I have managed to get today to work using the code:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A,Overview!J2,Sheet1!J:J)
```

Where `sheet1!A:A` is my date list, overview is `"=today()"` and `J:J` is the list of numbers to add.

This works perfectly, but when trying to add all sales between 2 dates, i.e. weeks sales, I am getting an error that I've entered too few arguments for this function.

I have start date and end date calculated by now functions.  My code is as follows:

```
=sumifs(Sheet1!J:J,">=J3",Sheet1!A:A,"<=J4")
```

`Sheet1!J:J` is the range of the items that need adding, `Sheet1!A:A` is the range for the dates, `J3` is the start date and `J4` is the end date.

I'm not sure how to add an example of my spread sheet but I would be happy to do so if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close, you just need to repeat the criteria in the `SUMIFS` function like so:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!J:J,Sheet1!A:A,">="&J3,Sheet1!A:A,"<="&J4)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your speedy reply.  I have tried this and am no longer getting an error, but it is now giving me a zero value as the result.  Could it be anything to do with how I have populated the date range?

Comment: @Scampiegem I just made a very recent edit, make sure you have the most recent version.

Comment: There is a distinct possibility I may have to kiss you x  On first attempt this looks to be good.  I shall test with my other criteria and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Can i be totally newb and just ask how I post code correctly to this site, I thought I had done it correctly but clearly not.

Comment: @Scampiegem - For in-line code use the back-tick (lower-case tilde) or `. To put the code in a new line select the whole line(s) and use Ctrl+K or just use four spaces at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @Scampiegem For a fuller listing, check out [this page.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Thanks @nicholas79171 day saved x

Comment: block (i.e. whole lines) code formatting needs a blank line before and after or it won't show.

Comment: @nicholas79171 do I do that by ticking the answer?  If so then yes, certainly!  IF I need to do something else then please let me know.  Thanks